# Use previous values of rows in data frame to build the current cell value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as represented here

```
   A     
0.001216  
0.000453
0.00506
0.004556
0.005266
```

I want to create a new column B something according to this formula presented in the code below.

```
column_key = 'B'
factor = 'A' 
df[column_key] = np.nan
df[column_key][0] = (df[factor][0] + 1) * 100
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df[column_key][i] = (df[factor][i] + 1) * df[column_key][i-1]
```

I have been trying to fill the current cell value using the previous cell of a column and adjacent cell of a column.

This is what I have tried but I don't think this is going to be effective.

Can anyone help me with best efficient approach of solving this problem?

Comment: Thanks, I am new to the community. Edited the question

Comment: Provide expected output too. Can you explain *fill the current cell value using the previous cell of a column and adjacent cell of a column* with some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas.cumprod()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html), it can be done in following way:

```
df['B'] = df['A'] + 1
df['B'][0] = df['B'][0] * 100
df['B'] = df['B'].cumprod()
```